# Does the Java compiler optimize type conversions when mixing numeric types?

Tags: java, type-conversion, integer, double, compiler-optimization

Could there be any difference in speed (however small) between Case 1 and Case 2 below?

```
double total = 12.34
double percentage = 56.78;
double amount;

// Case 1:
amount = (100 - percentage) * total;

// Case 2
amount = (100.0 - percentage) * total;
```

Or does Java automatically convert the integer literal (`100`) to a double (`100.0`) at compile time?

Comment: well, you could decompile the code and look ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Decompiled version shows that output will be same for both cases.

But as a best practice Case 2 will be more readable and understandable.

```
double d1 = 12.34D;
double d2 = 56.78D;

double d3 = (100.0D - d2) * d1;

d3 = (100.0D - d2) * d1;
```